# Publishing in different topics for each wheel

Tags: ros, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I (having a 6-wheeled robot and using the DiffDrivePlugin6w from hectorgazebo plugins) make that each wheel subscribes in a different topic: Now I've been able to make that all the wheels move at the same time (they are all "answering" to the cmd_vel topic), but I'd like something like cmd_vel_front_left topic,....

```
<gazebo>
  <plugin name="DiffDrivePlugin6W" filename="libdiffdrive_plugin_6w.so">
      <rosDebugLevel>Debug</rosDebugLevel>
      <publishWheelTF>false</publishWheelTF>
      <publishWheelJointState>true</publishWheelJointState>
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <frontLeftJoint>front_left_wheel_joint</frontLeftJoint>
      <frontRightJoint>front_right_wheel_joint </frontRightJoint>
      <midLeftJoint>medium_left_wheel_joint </midLeftJoint>
      <midRightJoint>medium_right_wheel_joint </midRightJoint>
      <rearLeftJoint>back_left_wheel_joint </rearLeftJoint>
      <rearRightJoint>back_right_wheel_joint </rearRightJoint>
      <wheelSeparation>0.569</wheelSeparation>
      <wheelDiameter>0.145</wheelDiameter>
      <wheelTorque>20</wheelTorque>
      <wheelAcceleration>1.8</wheelAcceleration>
      <commandTopic>cmd_vel</commandTopic>
      <odometryTopic>odom</odometryTopic>
      <odometryFrame>odom</odometryFrame>
      <odometrySource>world</odometrySource>
      <robotBaseFrame>base_link</robotBaseFrame>
      <updateRate>10.0</updateRate>
  </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

Thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216239/publishing-in-different-topics-for-each-wheel/) by [Ros_user](https://answers.ros.org/users/23239/ros_user/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-08-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-08-20**:
Please do not use CAPS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You would need to write a new driver for this.
The `DiffDrivePlugin6W` takes in the `/cmd_vel` topic for the `base_link` and not for each wheel seperately!
It then computes the single wheel velocities based on this command.

Thus, using this Plugin, you cannot do what you want without modification.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1